# How can I stop my SQL from returning empty data results?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I usually use Toad to manipulate my Oracle databases, but I even tried SQL manager for this one and it still would not work. I have a table with a few hundred records, and even running a simple 
    SELECT * FROM customer
will not work. There are no errors, and the data grid that displays pulls all the correct field column names but there are no records shown. What could be causing this?

Comment: How certain are you that there is data in the table?

Comment: We really need more data to go on.  Are you sure that table has any records?  Could you have added some but not committed?

Comment: 100% positive the table has data. It is committed. Other programs use the data, I am just trying the run statements on it in Toad

Comment: Toad sends your statement and returns the results. If you are not seeing the results there is something else going on. You can do a couple of additional tests to rule out a Toad specific issue. 1. Execute the statement in SQL*Plus. Type your statement in the Toad Editor and click the dropdown to the right of the execute as script button. It's the third from the left on the second row of the default Editor toolbar. There's an "Execute via SQL*Plus" menu item. Click it. 2. Place the caret on the table name of your SQL and press F4 to describe it. Does it resolve to the table you expect?

Comment: I did what you said, it finds the table, but the f4 description pane that pops up shows that the table has no records in it. I see in this pane the owner is a different user, but in the past I was able to run statements on it. Is this a user privilege issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your login schema own the table? If not, verify that any synonym is actually pointing to the object that you think it is. Preface the table name with its owning schema to rule out any conflicts.

Comment: It does not own the table, but I was able to run scripts on it in the past. I will look into this thanks!

Comment: You likely have a resolution conflict that is resolving the table to one other than you anticipate. If the owner is SCOTT for example doing SELECT * FROM SCOTT.CUSTOMER will force it to resolve to the object you are expecting. It's possible that someone added a public synonym having the same name as the table you are referencing and has it pointing to a table in a schema you are not expecting.

Comment: The issue was with the schema, so weird I had it working incorrectly for a little while...I think that is exactly what the issue was.